# What do I need to connect an LTO 6 Ultrium Internal Drive to a PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, backup, sata, lto

I bought an internal IBM LTO 6-H SAS Tape Drive to back up my data (I have many TBs). I don't have a server, only a Windows 10 and Windows 7 PC. Which wires/card/adapters/enclosures do I need so it can run via SATA or USB or even PCI-E or some port a PC would have. I have pictures of what I've got: an SAS Cable, the drive, and a card I thought was an SAS to PCI-e converter. any advice?

The card is a SUPERMICRO AOC-SAS2LP-MV8 PCI-Express 2.0 x8 SATA / SAS 8-Port Controller Card. The wire is Coboc SFF8087-MM-1M 1 meter 30AWG Internal Mini SAS 36-Pin SFF-8087 Male to Mini SAS 36-Pin SFF-8087 Male Cable.

The ports are pictured:
[image]

This is the card and the wire:
[image]

Comment: Can you please properly identify the card in question.  You indicate you think it’s PCI but that isn’t compatible with PCIe.

Comment: The card is a SUPERMICRO AOC-SAS2LP-MV8 PCI-Express 2.0 x8 SATA / SAS 8-Port Controller Card. The wire is Coboc SFF8087-MM-1M 1 meter 30AWG Internal Mini SAS 36-Pin SFF-8087 Male to Mini SAS 36-Pin SFF-8087 Male Cable

Answer (score 3):

The card has two SFF-8087 4xSAS connectors, but the tape drive has a SFF-8482. You'll need an adapter cable that will split the 4xSAS connection into four individual SAS connections, and allows a power connection too. [Something like this.](https://www.pc-pitstop.com/i3629)

The cable you currently have is intended for situations like connecting the card to a hot-plug disk backplane: each SFF-8087 connection can serve four SAS slots.

Once you get a suitable cable, you'll also need drivers for the card and the tape drive, and a backup program that is capable of using a tape drive.